# Is it possible to scrape table in image format

Tags: r, image, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm a novice in table scaping. I only know how to scrape wikitable at the moment. I'm looking for a way to scrape the tables (to have it in dataframe format) in the link below, mainly the first one. The tables are in image format. I have no idea how to do it.
https://africacenter.org/fr/spotlight/cartographie-des-facteurs-de-risque-de-propagation-du-covid-19-en-afrique/

Comment: You could use any OCR of your choice. Though this is a manual task rather than an automated task

Comment: You could use [`tesseract`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tesseract/vignettes/intro.html) and install the French training data, but it doesn't seem to like the tables from your link very much (too small? too many colours?) If you can get basic OCR to work, then use [page segmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087739/tesseract-ocr-text-order-for-documents-with-tables-or-rows) to parse the table. Good luck!

Comment: I tried tesseract but, it do not give me the right table